# How to adjust this URL rewrite to handle "dots" correctly...?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using the following URL rewrite rule:

```
#URL Rewriting
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?username=$1 [L]
```

This is working just fine for most accounts, but if the username has a dot in it (e.g. `User.Name`) then my rewrite is failing and the page won't load.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4736/3001761 - `[A-Za-z0-9-]` doesn't include `.`, so of course `User.Name` won't work.

Comment: Can you post your full .htaccess in question?

Answer (score 1):

I believe in your regex you could add `.` to catch it in user name so add it like this way. I am on mobile I haven't tested it should work I believe. Also this is a fix of OP's attempted code only. Added one more condition to check query string passed is null to avoid loop here.

```
##URL Rewriting
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-.]+)/?$ index.php?username=$1 [L]
```